# how to use primary key as foreign key more than once in a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a `Table_A` and a `Table_City`. In `Table_A` I have columns `current_city_Id` and `destination_city_Id`. I want to use the primary key of `Table_City` two times as foreign key (one for `current_city_Id` and `destination_city_Id`). How it is possible? It's giving me an error that foreign key already exists in this table. Please help me.

Comment: Could you show us `table_city` and what you tried for `table_a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one primary key, but you can have multiple columns in your primary key called Composite Primary Key.

A Table can have a Composite Primary Key which is a primary key made from two or more columns. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_City (
  current_city_Id INT,
  destination_city_Id INT,
  info char(200),
  primary key (current_city_Id, destination_city_Id)
);
```

You can also have Unique Indexes on your table, which will work a bit like a primary key in that they will enforce unique values, and will speed up querying of those values.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no limit on the number of foreign keys you can have in a table. Assuming table_city.id is table_city's primary key, and it's an integer...

```
create table table_a (
    current_city_Id integer references table_city(id)
    destination_city_Id integer references table_city(id)
);
```

Perhaps you've mistakenly declared them `primary key`?